# PowerPivot Tab gone

Tags: powerpivot

PowerPivot tab disappeared and isn't coming back. Working woth Excel 2010 / 32 bit.

Tried: Excel > Options > Add-ins > COM Add-ins and re-enabling PowerPivot, but to no avail.

Seriously stuck. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a computer reboot?

Comment: Thanks Frank! I found that it moved itself to the "disabled" category after it crashed. Not sure why it does that but I know where to look now.

Comment: @MotiLui Please post your solution as an answer and mark it solved for your question.

Comment: Me too... Excel 2016 / 64 bits - Windows 10... Reboot solves the problem... Microsoft, please...

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-install office with .Net Shared option enabled and follow the powerpivot installations guideline as provided in microsoft website.

There is no other way to enable it.